# Bind ViewModel to Controller on Edit Post Action - (with parameterless constructor) getting null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

As a developer asp.net web site I've created project. And Scaffold it for controller creation with DataBase First approach.

There are two EF data model objects: Personal and PersonalDetails.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class personalDetails
{
    public int personID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> rehber { get; set; }
    //many others, removed for easy to understand

}

public partial class personal
{
    public personal()
    {
        this.passportDetails = new HashSet<passportDetails>();
    }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<short> politicalPartyID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> familyStatusID { get; set; }

    public virtual familyStatus familyStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual politicalParties politicalParties { get; set; }

}
```

For a business logic it's necessary to create viewModel, because on view there are some fields from personal and some fields from personalDetils object. And I added viewModel class.

```
 public class SocialViewModels
{

    public personalDetails personalDetails { get; private set; }

    public personal personal { get; private set; }
    public SelectList marriageStatus { get; private set; }

    public SelectList partyList { get; private set; }
    public SocialViewModels()
    {

    }
    public SocialViewModels(personalDetails _personalDetails, personal _personal,  IEnumerable _marriageStatus, IEnumerable _partyList)
    {
        personalDetails = _personalDetails;
        personal=_personal;
        marriageStatus = new SelectList(_marriageStatus, "ID", "familyStatusName", personal.familyStatusID);
        partyList = new SelectList(_partyList, "ID", "partyName", personal.politicalPartyID);
    }

}
```

This ViewModel works well for get Details operation. Controller and View below:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        personalDetails personalDetails = db.personalDetails.Find(id);
        SocialViewModels svm = new SocialViewModels(personalDetails, personalDetails.personal, db.familyStatus, db.politicalParties);

        if (personalDetails == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(svm);
    }
```

Details view:

```
 @model kadrws.ViewModels.SocialViewModels

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.personal.familyStatus.familyStatusName)

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.personal.politicalParties.partyName)

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.personalDetails.rehber)

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Redaktə et", "Edit", new { id = Model.personal.ID })
</p>
```

But problem with Edit post method:

```
 // GET: personalDetails/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        personalDetails personalDetails = db.personalDetails.Find(id);
        SocialViewModels svm = new SocialViewModels(personalDetails, personalDetails.personal, db.familyStatus, db.politicalParties);

        if (personalDetails == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(svm);

    }

    // POST: personalDetails/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "personID,rehber, partyID, familyStatusID")] SocialViewModels scm )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
               //do 
        }
        ViewBag.personID = new SelectList(db.personal, "ID", "name", scm.personal.ID);
        return View(scm);
    }
```

Edit view :

```
@model kadrws.ViewModels.SocialViewModels
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.personalDetails.personID)

    @Html.DropDownList("personal_familyStatusID", Model.marriageStatus)

    @Html.DropDownList("personal_politicalPartyID", Model.partyList)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.personalDetails.rehber)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />

}
```

Problem is that, SocialViewModels is null. 
[image]

I also search similar behaviors in Google. Dozen this like problems. Please, help to understand where is problem in this code...

Comment: Your dropdwon lists have no relationship to your model. Your `[Bind]` attribute excludes almost everything from binding. But you misunderstanding what a view model is. It contains only those properties you want to display edit (its not a class to hold a lot of data models), and you never use a `[Bind]` attribute when you use a view model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke without bind a get also null object. So you prefer to me use FormCollection? there is not any another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, properties `marriageStatus` and `partyList` will be `null` because they are typeof `SelectList` (and you don't generate forms controls for each property of each `SelectListItem` in the collection - and nor should you). You do however generate `<select>` elements with names `personal_familyStatusID` and `personal_politicalPartyID` but your model does not include properties with those names.

Secondly, properties `personal` and `personalDetails` are `null` because you have include a `[Bind]` attribute which specifically excludes then (it would need to be `Bind(Include = "personal, personalDetails")]`.

However your misunderstanding what a view model is and how to use it. It is not just a class that holds multiple instances of data models, it should contain only those properties you display/edit in the view. Based on the 4 controls you have included in your form, your view model should be

```
public class SocialViewModels
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public Nullable<bool> Rehber { get; set; }
  public int MarriageStatus { get; set; }
  public int Party { get; set; }
  public SelectList MarriageStatusList { get; set; }
  public SelectList partyList { get; set; }
}
```

Side note: Do not use `private` set on your `SelectList` properties. If you needed to return the view because `ModelState` was invalid, then you could never repopulate them

Then in the GET method, initialize a new instance of the view model, set its properties from the data models and return it to the view

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
  ....
  personalDetails personalDetails = db.personalDetails.Find(id);
  ....
  SocialViewModels model = new SocialViewModels()
  {
    ID = personalDetails.personID,
    Rehber = personalDetails.rehber,
    MarriageStatus = personalDetails.personal.familyStatusID,
    ....
    MarriageStatusList = new SelectList(db.familyStatus, "ID", "familyStatusName"),
    ....
  };
  return View(model);
}
```

Side note: Your naming is extremely confusing (one minute its `familystatus`, then next its `marriagestatus`) so not sure if I have interpreted it correctly.

Then in the view

```
@model kadrws.ViewModels.SocialViewModels
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  ..
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MarriageStatus, Model.MarriageStatusList)
  ....
  @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.Rehber)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

And in the POST method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(SocialViewModels model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // repopulate your select lists
    return View(model);
  }
  // Get your data models, map the view model properties it
  // Save and redirect
}
```